# weird pdo sql update behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a sql `UPDATE` query in `PDO` that should update a name and a permissions string.
But instead it just places the id of that row inside all columns.

Here is my code:

```
public function saveRole($roleID, $name, $permissions)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE roles SET name = :name, permissions = :permissions WHERE id = :id";

    //this one sets a string variable in the PDO wrapper class
    PDO::setSQL($sql);

    //this one sets an array inside the PDO wrapper class
    PDO::setData([
        'name' => $name,
        'permissions' => $permissions,
        'id' => $roleID,
    ]);

    PDO::execute();

    return PDO::getResponse(true);
}
```

As you see, I've written a wrapper for PDO, which looks like this:

```
static function execute($sql = null, $data = null, $fetchmode = \PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
{
            //check if data and SQL are set in function call, if so, use function call params, if not use class params ($this->SQL & $this->data)
    self::connect();

    try
    {
        $stmnt = self::$con->prepare(self::$sql);

        $stmnt->setFetchMode($fetchmode);

        if (sizeof(self::$data) > 0)
        {
            foreach (self::$data as $key => $value)
            {
                $stmnt->bindParam(':' . $key, $value);
            }
        }

        $stmnt->execute();

        self::$stmnt = $stmnt;

        self::$data = [];
        self::$sql = '';

        self::$lastResponse = new pdoReturn(true, $stmnt);

        return;
    } catch (\PDOException $exception)
    {
        self::$data = [];
        self::$sql = '';

        self::$lastResponse = new pdoReturn(false, $exception);

        return;
    }
}

function setSQL($sql) { 
    if (!is_string($sql)) 
        return false; 
    if (strlen($sql) == 0) 
        return false; 
    $this->sql = $sql; 
    return true; 
} 

function setData($data) { 
    if (!is_array($data)) 
        return false; 
    $this->data = $data;
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: please show your `setData` method.

Comment: why does you class need to be `static`? Seems to be an unnessecary layer of faff, in my view.

Comment: Wrapping an already good Class is a waste of time, and only add unnecessary confusion

Comment: Your wrapper is static (so it cannot handle two simultaneous database connections) and interferes with PHP exceptions (so it cannot be used in a reasonably complex app or framework). Does it at least offer any feature that raw PDO doesn't?

Comment: i just switched to a non static version and still the same result... the weird thing si that it is just happening at this one little place, everywhere else in my application it just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> As you see, I've written a wrapper for PDO

For the immediate fix, change

```
   $stmnt = self::$con->prepare(self::$sql);
   $stmnt->setFetchMode($fetchmode);

    if (sizeof(self::$data) > 0)
    {
        foreach (self::$data as $key => $value)
        {
            $stmnt->bindParam(':' . $key, $value);
        }
    }

    $stmnt->execute();
```

to

```
    $stmnt = self::$con->prepare(self::$sql);
    $stmnt->setFetchMode($fetchmode);
    $stmnt->execute(self::$data);
```

Then read about [your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes) and fix other issues such as statefulness and error reporting.